# Codename One account & Push Notification Support

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play, codenameone

Codename One says, "Push notification is a pro only feature."

My Codename One account is Professional one now.

I uploaded my apk to google play store with this push notification feature.

So, if I downgrade or canceled this plan/subscription in codename one account, will my app in google play store not work any more for push notification?

And also will it be same about iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Push is a special case feature, it uses cloud servers. So while regular Codename One servers become irrelevant after build push servers are still relevant and tied to the subscription status. You can only send push messages thru them with a valid pro account or higher.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, Shai. Then, should I use pro account forever to use your Push notification in my small and simple app on google play store? Any other way to avoid this? This is too expensive for small app.

Comment: We don't have an option to avoid it. You can cancel and resume your subscription based on your development needs so if you don't need to send a push notification every month you can cancel and resubscribe.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. But I was asking if there is any other approach not to use the codenameone's push server. As I mentioned above, I published non-profit app to google play, which use push notification feature. Well, push notification is too expensive for the small app, so I'd like to cancel pro plan, keeping the app working forever. If you will stop push notification feature about non-pro account, I'd like to find any other push notification approach. If you can guide it to me, I will be very happy, Thanks again, Shai.

Comment: I answered that we don't support that. If it's a declared non-profit/charity you can probably contact us and we'll work something out but we need to keep servers running hence there is a cost.

Comment: Hi, Shai, How should I contact you? In my codename one account, support persons doesn't reply me as soon as enough.

Comment: Patience it sometimes takes a few hours